# Error loading type library/DLL

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2010, winapi

When I use the following code I get an compilation error

```
#import <dwmapi.lib>
#include <dwmapi.h>
```

I get the following error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open type
>   library file: 'c:\program
>   files\microsoft
>   sdks\windows\v7.0a\lib\dwmapi.lib':
>   Error loading type library/DLL.

Intellisense says:

> 2 IntelliSense: cannot open source
>   file "c:/users/####/documents/visual
>   studio
>   2010/Projects/modlauch/modlauch/Debug/dwmapi.tlh":
>   Bad file
>   descriptor    c:\users\####\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\projects\modlauch\modlauch\modlauchdlg.cpp   7   1   modlauch

**Does anyone know how to solve it?** I'm sure that my 'dwmapi' library is fine and there is nothing wrong with it. I'm using MFC with VS2010 , but I don't think that is related to the problem. (Platform - **Win32**)

If I get rid of "#import" then I get "unresolved external symbol __imp__DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea@8" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

dwmapi .lib is a type library? YOu sure its not just a plain old dll. A com lib is either .DLL or .tlb.

I think its a plain old dll. So you dont #import it you need instead

```
 #pragma comment(lib,"dwmapi.lib")
```

Answer (score 11):

This isn't the answer to your problem, but for others who arrive here with that error message - if you accidentally type `#import "Header.h"` rather than `#include "Header.h"` when including from a .lib then you will get that error.

Answer (score 0):

A type library is not a normal object library.

Type libraries are typically found in DLL's, OCX files and TLB files.

The few times I #import'ed a type library it always one of those, never a .LIB file.

Use the REGTLB or REGTLIB command (you may have to look this up in Google) to register a type library in your system.  It's similar to REGSVR32, but registers a type library rather than a COM component.

You can also use OLEVIEW to view the contents of a type library.